# Falla PSeInt - Error al salir de un Subproceso con pseudocódigo

Tags: algoritmos, pseint, pseudocódigo

tengo un inconveniente y creería yo que es error de PSeInt, les comento lo que sucede...

He creado un algoritmo (algo extenso), prácticamente todo funciona ok, sin embargo encuentro un ligero fallo y es que al salir de un único condicionar (Validar si la base de datos está llena) en un único subproceso (ingresar()), PSeInt no se sale sino que después de la línea (FinSubProceso), continua dentro del mismo proceso y se devuelve 4 líneas arriba, quedando de ésta manera dentro de un ciclo "Repetir" donde indica la finalización de un proceso de registro. Cabe aclarar que al darle la opción correcta para salir a éste ciclo, entonces ahí si que sale del Subproceso y va al menú en el proceso principal.

Todos los demás subprocesos me funcionan correctamente incluso el mismo subproceso siempre y cuando no entra en la condicional que indica que la base de datos (Vector en este caso) está llena.

Si alguien puede revisarlo en su PSeInt y decirme si les pasa lo mismo y quizás si hay alguna manera de controlar este evento, se los agradezco muchísimo. Copiaré el código separado por subprocesos ya que es muy largo y el mismo depende de todos los subalgoritmos, es por ello que no copio tan solo la parte del error.

**ALGORITMO PRINCIPAL**

```
Algoritmo tiendaComercial
    Definir  opciones, cantRegistros Como Entero;
    
    Escribir "Defina cuantos registros que tendrá la base de datos.";
    Leer cantRegistros;
    
    Escribir "===== > Creando la base de datos. < =====";
    Escribir  "";
    Dimension documento[cantRegistros], nombres[cantRegistros], saldo[cantRegistros], activo[cantRegistros];    
    
    Repetir
        Limpiar Pantalla;
        Escribir "************* MENÚ PRINCIPAL *************";
        Escribir "===== > Seleccione una opción (Número). < =====";
        Escribir  "1. Consultar.";
        Escribir  "2. Ordenar de menor a mayor.";
        Escribir  "3. Eliminar.";
        Escribir  "4. Ingresar.";
        Escribir  "9. Terminar.";
        
        Leer opciones;
        
        Segun opciones
            1:
                consultar(documento, nombres, saldo, activo, cantRegistros);
            2:
                ordenar(documento, nombres, saldo, activo, cantRegistros);
            3:
                eliminar(documento, nombres, saldo, activo, cantRegistros);
            4:
                ingresar(documento, nombres, saldo, activo, cantRegistros);
            9:
                Escribir "Finalizando sesión...";               
            De Otro Modo:
                Limpiar Pantalla;
                Escribir "************* MENÚ PRINCIPAL *************";
                Escribir "Opción no válida!, ingrese una opción válida...";
                Esperar 2 Segundos;
        FinSegun        
    Hasta Que opciones = 9  
FinAlgoritmo
```

**SUBALGORITMO PARA CONSULTA DE REGISTROS**

```
//Creando Subproceso para consultar registros
SubProceso consultar (documento Por Referencia, nombres Por Referencia, saldo Por Referencia, activo Por Referencia, cantRegistros Por Valor)
    Definir option, registro Como Entero;   
    Definir respuesta Como Logico;
    Limpiar Pantalla;   
    
    Escribir "===== CONSULTANDO UN REGISTRO =====";
    Escribir "Seleccione 1. Consultar por documento.";
    Escribir "Seleccione 2. Listar todos los registros.";   
    Escribir "Seleccione 3. Salir.";    
    Leer option;
    Escribir "";
    
    Repetir     
        Segun option
            1:
                Escribir "Ingrese el documento a consultar";
                Leer registro;
                
                //Buscamos en los registros el documento ingresado
                Para i = 0 Hasta cantRegistros-1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
                    si registro = documento[i] Entonces
                        respuesta = Verdadero;              
                    FinSi
                FinPara
                
                // Verificamos si la búsqueda arrojó algun resultado
                si respuesta = Verdadero Entonces                   
                    // Si lo encontró mostramos la información del registro
                    Para i = 0 Hasta cantRegistros-1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
                        si registro = documento[i] Entonces
                            Limpiar Pantalla;
                            Escribir "";
                            Escribir "===== CONSULTANDO UN REGISTRO =====";
                            Escribir "Documento: ", documento[i];
                            Escribir "Nombres: ", nombres[i];
                            Escribir "Saldo: $", saldo[i];
                            
                            si activo[i] = "1" Entonces
                                Escribir "Activo: SI";
                            SiNo
                                Escribir "Activo: NO";
                            FinSi                           
                            Escribir "";
                            Escribir "Presione ENTER para regresar al menú principal";
                            Esperar Tecla;
                        FinSi
                    FinPara
                SiNo
                    Repetir
                        // Si el registro no existe, informamos que no se encontró
                        Limpiar Pantalla;                   
                        Escribir "===== CONSULTANDO UN REGISTRO =====";
                        Escribir "Ooops!! Registro no encontrado ¿Desea registrarlo?";
                        Escribir "1. Si";
                        Escribir "2. No";               
                        Leer option;
                        
                        Segun option
                            1:
                                ingresar(documento, nombres, saldo, activo, cantRegistros);                 
                            2:                              
                                Limpiar Pantalla;
                                Escribir "===== CONSULTANDO UN REGISTRO =====";
                                Escribir "Saliendo del proceso de consulta...";
                                Esperar 2 Segundos;
                            De Otro Modo:
                                Escribir "Opción incorrecta! elige una opción válida...";
                                Esperar 2 Segundos;
                        FinSegun
                    Hasta Que option = 2
                FinSi
                option = 3;
            2:
                // Verificamos posiciones llenas en el vector   
                cantReg = disponibilidad (documento, cantRegistros);
                
                si cantReg > 0 Entonces
                    Limpiar Pantalla;
                    Escribir "===== LISTANDO TODOS REGISTROS =====";
                    // Listamos todos los registros de la base datos
                    listar(documento, nombres, saldo, activo, cantReg);
                    Escribir "";
                    Escribir "Presione ENTER para continuar...";
                    Esperar Tecla;
                    option = 3;
                SiNo
                    Limpiar Pantalla;
                    Escribir "===== LISTANDO TODOS REGISTROS =====";
                    Escribir "La base de datos está vacía!";
                    Escribir "";
                    Esperar 2 Segundos;
                    option = 3;
                FinSi               
            3:
                Escribir "Regresando al menú principal...";
                Escribir "";
                Esperar 2 Segundos;
            De Otro Modo:
                Limpiar Pantalla;
                Escribir "===== LISTANDO TODOS REGISTROS =====";
                Escribir "Opción incorrecta!, elige una opción válida...";
                Escribir "";
                Esperar 2 Segundos;
                consultar(documento, nombres, saldo, activo, cantRegistros);
        FinSegun        
    Hasta Que option = 3
FinSubProceso
```

**SUBALGORITMO PARA INGRESAR REGISTROS**

```
//Creando Subproceso para ingresar registros
SubProceso ingresar (documento Por Referencia, nombres Por Referencia, saldo Por Referencia, activo Por Referencia, cantRegistros Por Valor)
    Definir option, indice, cantReg, nDocumento Como Entero;
    Definir detener, dupliDocumento, dupliNombre, continuar Como Logico;
    Definir nNombre Como Caracter;  
    
    continuar = Falso;
    
    // Verificamos posiciones llenas en el vector   
    cantReg = disponibilidad (documento, cantRegistros);
    
    si cantReg > 0 Entonces
        indice = (cantReg + 1)-1;
    SiNo
        indice = 0;
    FinSi       
    
    si cantReg = cantRegistros Entonces
        Repetir
            Limpiar Pantalla;
            Escribir "===== CREANDO NUEVO REGISTRO =====";
            Escribir "No hay espacios libres en la base de datos...";
            Escribir "=== > ¿Desea eliminar un registro?..  ";
            Escribir "1. Si";
            Escribir "2. No";
            Leer option;
            
            segun option
                1:
                    eliminar(documento, nombres, saldo, activo, cantRegistros);
                2:
                    Escribir "Regresando al menú principal...";
                    Esperar 2 Segundos;
                De Otro Modo:
                    Escribir "Opción no válida!, elige una opción válida...";
                    Esperar 2 Segundos;
            FinSegun
        Hasta Que option = 2;
    FinSi
    
    Si cantReg < cantRegistros Entonces
        Repetir
            Limpiar Pantalla;
            Escribir "===== CREANDO NUEVO REGISTRO =====";
            Repetir
                Escribir "Escriba documento a registrar...";
                Leer nDocumento;                
                dupliDocumento = validador(documento, nombres, cantRegistros, nDocumento, 1);
                
                si dupliDocumento = Verdadero Entonces
                    Escribir "Este documento ya existe!...";
                    Escribir "";
                    continuar = Falso;
                SiNo
                    Repetir
                        Escribir "Escriba el nombre del cliente...";
                        Leer nNombre;
                        dupliNombre = validador(documento, nombres, cantRegistros, nNombre, 2);
                        
                        Si dupliNombre = Verdadero Entonces
                            Escribir "";
                            Escribir "Nombre ya existe con documento diferente, ¿desea registrarlo?.";
                            Escribir "Escriba 1. Si quiero registrarlo";
                            Escribir "Escriba 2. No quiero elegir otro nombre";
                            Leer option;
                            
                            segun option
                                1:
                                    continuar = Verdadero;
                                De Otro Modo:
                                    continuar = Falso;                              
                            FinSegun
                        SiNo
                            continuar = Verdadero;
                        FinSi                       
                    Hasta Que continuar = Verdadero;
                FinSi               
            Hasta Que continuar = Verdadero;
            documento[indice] = nDocumento;
            nombres[indice] = nNombre;
            
            Escribir "Escriba el saldo del cliente...";
            Leer saldo[indice];
            Repetir
                Escribir "¿Cliente activo? 1= SI 2= NO...";
                Leer activo[indice];
            Hasta Que activo[indice] = "2" o activo[indice] = "1"
            
            ordenados(documento, nombres, saldo, activo, cantRegistros, 1);
            Repetir
                Limpiar Pantalla;
                Escribir "===== REGISTRO EXITOSO =====";
                Escribir "¿Desea agregar otro registro?.. 1 = SI, 2 = NO";
                Leer option;
                
                Segun option
                    1:
                        ingresar(documento, nombres, saldo, activo, cantRegistros);                                 
                    2:
                        detener = Verdadero;
                        Escribir "Regresando al menú principal...";
                        Esperar 2 Segundos;
                    De Otro Modo:                   
                        Escribir "Opción incorrecta!, regresando al menú principal...";
                        Esperar 2 Segundos; 
                FinSegun
            Hasta Que option =2;
        Hasta Que detener = Verdadero;
    FinSi
FinSubProceso
```

**SUBALGORITMO PARA ELIMINAR REGISTROS**

```
//Creando Subproceso para eliminar registros
SubProceso eliminar (documento Por Referencia, nombres Por Referencia, saldo Por Referencia, activo Por Referencia, cantRegistros Por Valor)
    Definir option, auxiliar, totalRegistros, cantReg Como Entero;
    
    // Verificamos posiciones llenas en el vector   
    cantReg = disponibilidad (documento, cantRegistros);    
    
    Escribir "===== ELIMINAR UN REGISTRO =====";
    Escribir "Actualmente estos son los registros de la base de datos, ¿Cual desea eliminar?...";   
    listar(documento, nombres, saldo, activo, cantReg); 
    Leer option;
    
    si option-1 >= cantReg Entonces
        Limpiar Pantalla;
        Escribir "===== ELIMINAR UN REGISTRO =====";
        Escribir "El registro a eliminar no existe!.. Regresando";
        Esperar 2 Segundos;
    SiNo
        auxiliar = option;
        
        Mientras auxiliar <= cantReg-1 Hacer
            // Eliminando el registro
            documento[option-1] = documento[auxiliar];
            nombres[option-1] = nombres[auxiliar];
            saldo[option-1] = saldo[auxiliar];
            activo[option-1] = activo[auxiliar];
            
            auxiliar = auxiliar+1;
        Fin Mientras
        
        documento[auxiliar-1] = 0;
        nombres[auxiliar-1] = "";
        saldo[auxiliar-1] = 0;
        activo[auxiliar-1] = "";        
        
        // Reordenamos la lista de la base de datos
        ordenados(documento, nombres, saldo, activo, cantRegistros, 1);
        // Verificamos posiciones llenas en el vector   
        cantReg = disponibilidad (documento, cantRegistros);    
        
        Limpiar Pantalla;
        // Mostramos los registros restantes
        Escribir "===== Registro eliminado con éxito. =====";   
        Si cantReg > 0 Entonces
            listar(documento, nombres, saldo, activo, cantReg);
            Escribir "";
            Escribir "Presione ENTER para salir";
            Esperar Tecla;
        SiNo
            Escribir "¡URRAAA!.. La base de datos ahora está vacía!";
            Escribir "";
            Escribir "Presione ENTER para regresar al menú Principal";
            Esperar Tecla;
        FinSi
    FinSi   
FinSubProceso
```

**SUBALGORITMO PARA ESTABLECER UN ORDEN EN LOS REGISTROS**

```
//Creando Subproceso para ordenar los registros
SubProceso ordenar (documento Por Referencia, nombres Por Referencia, saldo Por Referencia, activo Por Referencia, cantRegistros Por Valor)
    Definir orden, cantReg Como Entero;
    
    // Verificamos posiciones llenas en el vector   
    cantReg = disponibilidad (documento, cantRegistros);
    
    Si cantReg > 1 Entonces
        Repetir
            Limpiar Pantalla;
            Escribir "===== Orden actual de la base de datos =====";
            listar(documento, nombres, saldo, activo, cantReg);
            
            Escribir "";
            Escribir "Seleccione 1. Para ordenar de MENOR a MAYOR por Documento";
            Escribir "Seleccione 2. Para ordenar de MAYOR a MENOR por Documento";
            Leer orden;
            
            Si orden < 1 o orden > 2 Entonces
                Escribir "";
                Escribir "Opción incorrecta!, elige una opción válida...";
                Esperar 2 Segundos;
            FinSi
        Hasta Que orden <= 2
        
        ordenados(documento, nombres, saldo, activo, cantRegistros, orden);
        
        Escribir "";
        Escribir "===== Base de datos Ordenada  =====";
        listar(documento, nombres, saldo, activo, cantReg);
        Escribir "";
        Escribir "Presione ENTER para volver al menú principal...";
        Esperar Tecla;
    SiNo
        Si cantReg = 1 Entonces
            Limpiar Pantalla;
            Escribir "===== ORDENAR BASE DE DATOS =====";
            listar(documento, nombres, saldo, activo, cantReg);
            Escribir "";
            Escribir "No hay suficientes registros para ordenar.";
            Escribir "Presione ENTER para regresar al menú princial...";
            Esperar Tecla;
        SiNo
            Limpiar Pantalla;
            Escribir "===== ORDENAR BASE DE DATOS =====";
            Escribir "Esta base de datos no tiene registros para ordenar...";
            Esperar 2 Segundos;
        FinSi
    FinSi   
FinSubProceso
```

**SUBALGORITMO PARA ORDENAR REGISTROS SEGUN ORDEN ENVIADO**

```
// Estableciendo orden general
SubProceso ordenados (documento Por Referencia, nombres Por Referencia, saldo Por Referencia, activo Por Referencia, cantRegistros Por Valor, nOrden Por Valor)
    Definir cantReg Como Entero;
    
    Segun nOrden        
        1:          
            // Ordeno de Mayor a menor segun la cantidad total de cupos
            Para i=0 Hasta cantRegistros-1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
                Para j=i+1 Hasta cantRegistros-1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
                    si documento[i] < documento[j] Entonces
                        //Ordenando los documentos
                        tmpDocumento = documento[i];
                        documento[i] = documento[j];
                        documento[j] = tmpDocumento;
                        
                        //Ordenando los nombres
                        tmpNombre = nombres[i];
                        nombres[i] = nombres[j];
                        nombres[j] = tmpNombre;
                        
                        //Ordenando los saldos
                        tmpSaldo = saldo[i];
                        saldo[i] = saldo[j];
                        saldo[j] = tmpSaldo;
                        
                        //Ordenando los activos
                        tmpActivo = activo[i];
                        activo[i] = activo[j];
                        activo[j] = tmpActivo;                          
                    FinSi
                FinPara
            FinPara
            
            // Verifico cuantos cupos hay llenos 
            cantReg = disponibilidad (documento, cantRegistros);
            
            // Ordeno de Menor a Mayor unicamente los cupos que contienen datos en el vector
            Para i=0 Hasta cantReg-1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
                Para j=i+1 Hasta cantReg-1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
                    si documento[i] > documento[j] Entonces
                        //Ordenando los documentos
                        tmpDocumento = documento[i];
                        documento[i] = documento[j];
                        documento[j] = tmpDocumento;
                        
                        //Ordenando los nombres
                        tmpNombre = nombres[i];
                        nombres[i] = nombres[j];
                        nombres[j] = tmpNombre;
                        
                        //Ordenando los saldos
                        tmpSaldo = saldo[i];
                        saldo[i] = saldo[j];
                        saldo[j] = tmpSaldo;
                        
                        //Ordenando los activos
                        tmpActivo = activo[i];
                        activo[i] = activo[j];
                        activo[j] = tmpActivo;                          
                    FinSi
                FinPara
            FinPara
        2:
            // Ordeno de Mayor a menor segun la cantidad total de cupos
            Para i=0 Hasta cantRegistros-1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
                Para j=i+1 Hasta cantRegistros-1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
                    si documento[i] < documento[j] Entonces
                        //Ordenando los documentos
                        tmpDocumento = documento[i];
                        documento[i] = documento[j];
                        documento[j] = tmpDocumento;
                        
                        //Ordenando los nombres
                        tmpNombre = nombres[i];
                        nombres[i] = nombres[j];
                        nombres[j] = tmpNombre;
                        
                        //Ordenando los saldos
                        tmpSaldo = saldo[i];
                        saldo[i] = saldo[j];
                        saldo[j] = tmpSaldo;
                        
                        //Ordenando los activos
                        tmpActivo = activo[i];
                        activo[i] = activo[j];
                        activo[j] = tmpActivo;                          
                    FinSi
                FinPara
            FinPara     
    FinSegun    
FinSubProceso
```

**SUBALGORITMO PARA CONTAR REGISTROS EN EL VECTOR**

```
// Creamos función para contar las posiciones llenas en el vector
Funcion totalRegistros <- disponibilidad (documento Por Referencia, cantRegistros Por Valor)
    // Verificamos posiciones llenas en el vector
    Para i=0 hasta cantRegistros-1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
        si documento[i] <> 0 Entonces
            totalRegistros = totalRegistros+1;
        FinSi
    FinPara 
FinFuncion
```

**SUBALGORITMO PARA LISTAR LOS REGISTROS DE LOS VECTORES**

```
// Proceso para listar todos los registros de la base de datos
SubProceso listar (documento Por Referencia, nombres Por Referencia, saldo Por Referencia, activo Por Referencia, cantRegistros Por Valor)
    
    Para  i=0 Hasta cantRegistros-1 Con Paso 1 Hacer        
        si activo[i] = "1" Entonces         
            Escribir i+1,". Documento: ", documento[i], ", Nombre: ", nombres[i], ", Saldo: ", saldo[i], ", ¿Activo?: SI";
        SiNo            
            Escribir i+1,". Documento: ", documento[i], ", Nombre: ", nombres[i], ", Saldo: ", saldo[i], ", ¿Activo?: NO";
        FinSi
    FinPara
FinSubProceso
```

**SUBALGORITMO PARA VALIDAR REGISTROS DUPLICADOS**

```
Funcion duplicado <- validador (documento Por Referencia, nombres Por Referencia, cantRegistros Por Valor, regValidar Por Valor, vectorValidar Por Valor)
    
    Segun vectorValidar
        1:
            Para  i=0 Hasta cantRegistros-1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
                si regValidar = documento[i] Entonces
                    duplicado = Verdadero;
                FinSi
            FinPara
        2:
            Para  i=0 Hasta cantRegistros-1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
                si regValidar = nombres[i] Entonces
                    duplicado = Verdadero;
                FinSi
            FinPara
    FinSegun        
FinFuncion
```

Desde ya, gracias por tomarte el tiempo de revisarlo y decirme si te sucede el mismo fallo que me presenta.

RECUERDA: El fallo es cuando intentas hacer un nuevo registro estando los vectores llenos, puedes establecer un tamaño de vector de 1 elementos, registrarlo e intentar registrar de nuevo otro, te dirá que la base de datos está llena y te pregunta si quieres eliminar 1 registro, al indicar la opción 2, justo ahí es cuando no se sale del subproceso y se devuelve a la línea que indico al inicio de la pregunta.

Adjunto algunas capturas que describen la falla.

1.Muestra cuando llega al final del Subproceso
[image: Muestra cuando llega al final del Subproceso]

2.Muestra la línea a la que salta sin salir del subproceso
[image: Muestra la línea a la que salta sin salir del subproceso]

3.Muestra el ciclo en el que queda luego de fallar la salida del subproceso
[image: Muestra el ciclo en el que queda luego de fallar la salida del subproceso]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es un bug en pseint, sino un error en cómo interpreta lo que ocurre en el paso a paso. Invoca por primera vez a la función "ingresar" desde el menú; y luego cuando pregunta si hay que ingresar otro y el usuario dice que sí, la función se invoca nuevamente a sí misma (linea 238 según su captura de pantalla). Entonces, la 1er invocación queda en esa linea a la espera de que se resuelva la 2da. Cuando dice que la ejecución vuelve 4 lineas para atrás, lo que ocurre en realidad es que termina la ejecución de la 2da llamada a ingresar y retorna a la 1ra (y allí la instrucción que sigue es el finsegun).

Por otro lado, para reportar un error es buena práctica tratar de reducir el código a la mínima expresión posible donde se manifieste, para facilitar su reproducción y depuración.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me dio claridad sobre lo que podía estar pasando, organicé el código de manera que me cumpliera las validaciones que necesitaba y eliminé las rellamadas al mismo procedimiento dentro de si mismo y si ha funcionado. Hice las pruebas y todo va excelente.

Answer (score 0):

Pensé en esta solución que funciona, pero continúo creyendo que PSeInt presenta fallas, ya que he realizado pruebas y el error se puede omitir pero sigue estando...

**SOLUCIÓN PARCIAL**
Hice el proceso para mostrar el menú en un subalgoritmo aparte, le pasé los vectores como parámetros incluyendo el tamaño de los mismos, luego he llamado al subproceso en cada una de las partes de los demás subprocesos donde requiero regresar al menú principal, de esta manera evitaría el bache o la falla que me estaba presentando al salir de determinado subproceso y regresar al algoritmo principal. Así ha quedado.

**SUBALGORITMO PARA MOSTRAR EL MENU PRINCIPAL**

```
SubAlgoritmo menuPrincipal(documento Por Referencia, nombres Por Referencia, saldo Por Referencia, activo Por Referencia, cantRegistros Por Valor)
    
    Repetir
        Limpiar Pantalla;
        Escribir "************* MENÚ PRINCIPAL *************";
        Escribir "===== > Seleccione una opción (Número). < =====";
        Escribir  "1. Consultar.";
        Escribir  "2. Ordenar de menor a mayor.";
        Escribir  "3. Eliminar.";
        Escribir  "4. Ingresar.";
        Escribir  "9. Terminar.";
        
        Leer opciones;
        
        Segun opciones
            1:
                consultar(documento, nombres, saldo, activo, cantRegistros);
            2:
                ordenar(documento, nombres, saldo, activo, cantRegistros);
            3:
                eliminar(documento, nombres, saldo, activo, cantRegistros);
            4:
                ingresar(documento, nombres, saldo, activo, cantRegistros);
            9:
                Escribir "Finalizando sesión...";               
            De Otro Modo:
                Limpiar Pantalla;
                Escribir "************* MENÚ PRINCIPAL *************";
                Escribir "Opción no válida!, ingrese una opción válida...";
                Esperar 2 Segundos;
        FinSegun        
    Hasta Que opciones = 9
    
FinSubAlgoritmo
```

En la siguiente parte observamos como hago uso de este nuevo subalgoritmo en la parte donde se me presentaba el error, y es que cuando se iba a ingresar un nuevo registro en los vectores pero el mismo no tenía índices vacíos, nos dice que la base de datos está llena y nos sugiere eliminar un registro, si la opción era 2, entonces no se salía del subproceso, sino que retornaba dentro del mismo 4 líneas de código quedando en dentro de un ciclo que al dar nuevamente la opción 2 entonces si se salía del subproceso.

Con la solución lo que hago es invocar directamente el subproceso al que quiero regresar.

**USO DEL SUBALGORITMO PARA MOSTRAR EL MENU PRINCIPAL**

```
si cantReg = cantRegistros Entonces
        Repetir
            Limpiar Pantalla;
            Escribir "===== CREANDO NUEVO REGISTRO =====";
            Escribir "No hay espacios libres en la base de datos...";
            Escribir "=== > ¿Desea eliminar un registro?..  ";
            Escribir "1. Si";
            Escribir "2. No";
            Leer option;
            
            segun option
                1:
                    eliminar(documento, nombres, saldo, activo, cantRegistros);
                2:
                    Escribir "Regresando al menú principal...";
                    Esperar 2 Segundos;                 
                    menuPrincipal(documento, nombres, saldo, activo, cantRegistros);
                De Otro Modo:
                    Escribir "Opción no válida!, elige una opción válida...";
                    Esperar 2 Segundos;
            FinSegun
        Hasta Que option = 2;
    FinSi
```

**EL ERROR PERSISTE**
Luego de invocar el subalgoritmo para mostrar el menú principal después de ir desde de la línea de código donde estaba el error, al presionar en este caso la opción 9. si que sale del subalgoritmo `menuPrincipal()` pero me regresa al mismo subalgoritmo anterior `ingresar()` y se puede evidenciar de nuevo la falla.

Comment: ESto es una respuesta? o un comentario a tu pregunta?

Comment: saludos @gbianchi, era una respuesta ante una posible solución que había encontrado, sin embargo la falla continuaba persistiendo, posteriormente reorganicé el código siguiendo las ideas principales que me brindó el usuario Zaskar y he logrado que no se presente mas el bug o falla que se me presentaba al ejecutar el código.

Comment: Podrias reorganizar la respuesta, para que se entienda cual es la respuesta?

Comment: @gbianchi de hecho creo que lo hice lo mas organizado que creo puedo llegar a hacerla, solo se trataba de mostrar una "POSIBLE" solución, llamando al mismo método dentro de si mismo, igual no solucionaba la falla porque el proceso quedaba sin terminar. Ya con la respuesta que me dio el usuario Zaskar, fue suficiente para organizar el código y solucionar la falla presentada. Si tienes una sugerencia distinta, te agradecerías me ayudes a complementarla ya que como digo no era una solución definitiva. Soy nuevo en el mundo del desarrollo y en la comunidad. Disculpas si no soy claro.